# How to register a custom UICollectinViewCell into a UICollectionView built inside a custom view in a xib file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionviewcell, xcode9

This is how I tried to do it but didn't work
and the output is a blank collection view as you see in the simulator.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks
[image: This is the code of the collectionViewCell]

[image]

[image]

Comment: We can not figure out the problem so easily you can attach a project example

Comment: Please find my answer, it is working perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on **DonationProgramCell.swift**
add Property Observers to titleText property like this

```
var titleText = "" {
        willSet {
            itemTitle.text = newValue
        }
    }
```

also make sure that the **itemTitle** IBOutlet Label has right constraints

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it is working for me,

```
fileprivate let cellIdentifier = String(describing: DonationProgramCell.self)
```

On `viewDidLoad()`

```
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: cellIdentifier, bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
```

now on `cellForItemAt indexPath` use it like this,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! DonationProgramCell
    //cell.updateCellView(title: dataArray[indexPath.row])
    cell.itemTitle.text = dataArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

**UPDATE**

update your `updateCellView` method like this, no need to take `titleText` variable

```
func updateCellView(title: String) {
    self.itemTitle.text = title
}
```

Comment: that was to avoid the found nil error while unwrapping the optional value of the outlet; thats why I set the text label value in the awakeFromNib method

Comment: I tried it already, and this method just updates the textLabel it does not relate to the problem

Comment: I am not sure. that could be

Comment: Nope, it's not. Thanks for your help any way

Answer (score 0):

Verify constraints of your collection view and size of cell.
If height of collection view is 0, collection view won't reload data.
If I'm right, try to reload data on viewWillAppear.

Comment: The collection view height is okay. It's the grey rectangle in the simulator above

Comment: Ok, try to remove identifier inside xib and clean the project. it could work strange in some cases.

Comment: I tried that already removed the views and controllers and started over its the same

Comment: Is method cellForItemAt called? If not, try to set layout delegate to self and implement method of UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;